# Dynamic binding of fields with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Please see the following example I have created.
https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/5vh67sod/4/

In this example, the 'Allowances' model contains various attributes. Out of these attributes, for a particular allowance, which attributes are to be shown on screen are contained in  'fields' array.

In the following HTML code,

```
<div data-bind="foreach : allowanceList">
  <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
    <span data-bind="text : allowanceTitle"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left : 20px" data-bind="foreach : fields">
    <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
      <label data-bind="text : title"></label>
      <!-- ko if : typeOfField() == "input"-->
      <input data-bind="value : '$parentContext.' + allowanceVariable() " />
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

I want to bind `<input>` to the attribute of allowanceList's object whose name is contained in the value of `'allowanceVariable'` variable of `'fields'` array.

For example, for the first iteration of `allowanceList` and first iteration of `fields`, the `allowanceVariable()` has value of *'hours'*.
Hence, for this iteration, I want to bind the `<input>` to *'hours'* field of the `allowanceList's` current object.

As seen in the fiddle, at present, knockout only copies *$parentContext.hours* into input.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer, you are hardcoding the `allowanceVariable`s and checking them individually using if-else chains. For every property you add, you'd have to update the `if-else` block. It works, but they are no longer *dynamic* `fields`.

Instead, [you can use the keyword `as` and give an alias to your `foreach` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items) like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: allowanceList, as: '_allowance'}">
  <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
    <span data-bind="text : allowanceTitle"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left : 20px" data-bind="foreach: { data: _allowance.fields, as: '_field'}">
    <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
      <label data-bind="text : title"></label>
      <!-- ko if : typeOfField() == "input"-->
      <input data-bind="value : _allowance[_field.allowanceVariable()]" />
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5vh67sod/5/)

---

Mind you, we can make it work without alias as well. Use the `$parent` and `$data` [binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach : allowanceList">
  <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
    <span data-bind="text : allowanceTitle"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left : 20px; display : block; width : 100%" data-bind="foreach : fields">
    <div style="display : block; width : 100%">
      <label data-bind="text : title"></label>
      <!-- ko if : typeOfField() == "input"-->
      <input data-bind="value : $parent[$data.allowanceVariable()]" />
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9fq59gfc/2/)

But, I think the former approach is cleaner and easily understandable. Great stuff on creating neat fiddles by the way :)

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using function inside the model, the desired result can be achieved.
Following is the fiddle which demonstrates the answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/9fq59gfc/1/

Here, I have called `dynamicValue` function of the `Field` model of inner for loop and 
I have passed `$parent` object to it.

In the function, I have checked the value of  `allowanceVariable` and accordingly returned value of corresponding variable of `Allowance` model.

Please suggest any other better solution if applicable as in this solution, I have to hard code names of attributes of `Allowance` model in the `dynamicValue` function, but, this definitely solves my problem.